# delay in hiding loader icon after $stateChangeSuccess

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ng-if, angularjs-rootscope

I know there's a lot written about this, but I can't find a solution to this particular problem. When changing a state, I want the current state to be hidden and for the spinner to be displayed on `$stateChangeStart`, and for the spinner to be hidden when the new state is resolved on `$stateChangeSuccess`.  Currently, I'm dealing with this by setting showSpinner value to true/false in the $rootScope where it is being reflected in the views, like so...

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        $rootScope.showSpinner = true;
    })

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        $rootScope.showSpinner = false;
    })
```

Views:

```
<div class="spinner" ng-if="showSpinner"></div>
<div ng-if="!showSpinner" ng-show="$state.includes('rulebook.text-view')" ui-view="text-view"></div>
<div ng-if="!showSpinner" ng-show="$state.includes('rulebook.rules')" ui-view="rules"></div>
<div ng-if="!showSpinner" ng-show="$state.includes('rulebook.vocab')" ui-view="vocab"></div>
```

As of now $stateChangeStart is doing what I want, but there is a good delay in removing the spinner after the new view has been resolved on $stateChangeSuccess and the content has been rendered.  Can't really figure why this is happening.  I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [$viewContentLoaded](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#view-load-events) event mentioned in angular router user guide?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but I've tried working with $viewContextLoaded.  The event is firing.  I've tried placing $rootScope.showSpinner=false inside that event and removing $stateChangeSuccess.  This prevents the event from firing (the spinner keeps spinning).